# Issue understanding solving a maze recursively using Divide and Conquer

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, divide-and-conquer

I am trying to solve a maze recursively using d&c for an assignment. I have read up on what the d&c algorithm is, but I am having trouble wrapping my head around how to use it in my program recursively. I am able to get the program to print out the maze showing that the program has traveled the entire maze, and print out the exit coordinates, but I can’t get it to show only the shortest correct path (rather than showing it running through every spot in the maze). I also have a problem where it is printing out both the exit coordinates and starting coordinate which is not what I want it to do.

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated. I’m not looking directly for a “this is how you do it” but rather try this approach or d&c should really be used like this.

I’ve also included my recursive method. A maze consists of a board of 1’s for boundaries and all available paths are 0’s; when a 0 is checked and traveled it is turned into a 2.

```
public int RecursiveRead(int row, int column, int pathLength) {
        try {
        if (maze[row][column] == 1) {
            return -1;
        }

        if (maze[row][column] == 0) {
            maze[row][column] = 2;
            return 1 + (Math.min(Math.min(RecursiveRead(row + 1, column, pathLength + 1), RecursiveRead(row - 1, column, pathLength + 1)),
                    Math.min(RecursiveRead(row, column + 1, pathLength + 1), RecursiveRead(row, column - 1, pathLength + 1))));
        }
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            maze[row][column] = 2;
            System.out.println("Exit is: (" + row + ", " + column + ")");
        }

        return 1;
    }
public void MazeSolver() {
        if (RecursiveRead(1, 0, 0) == -1) {
            System.out.println("There is no exit");
            return;
        } else {

            try {
                FileWrite();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return;
```

EDIT:
Clarified Question:
I am wondering how to use divide and conquer to recursively find the shortest path to an exit, or if an exit doesn't exist.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post a [mcve].

Comment: Can you list the questions you have clearly? It seems that you have more than one concern

Comment: Also please _edit your question_, don't say "edit: ....", take the time to take the effort to rewrite your question to be [a good question](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Separate your maze calculations from your maze output.  Look up depth-first search to see how to not only find a path through a maze but also to output the shortest path.

Comment: Several good relevant articles come up when I do a Google search for *maze divide and conquer*